# Why are these onedrive commands running on boot

Tags: boot, cmd.exe, onedrive

I don't have Onedrive installed.

```
""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /q /c del /q "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\Update\OneDriveSetup.exe"" 
""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /q /c rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx\amd64"" -cur_console:c
```

(x's are some sort of number)

Why does my computer run these commands on boot?